# Xamarin Forms: Propertychanged is not triggered when refreshing from database

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, fody-propertychanged

I'm having an object in my viewmodel which consists of an Id and some other attributes.
my equality check contains the check on Id, so I can identify items in lists when refreshing.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
            return Equals(obj as Class);
        }
public bool Equals(Class other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.Id.Equals(other.Id);
        }
```

Now when I'm on a detailPage which is only having one item, I want to manually refresh that item from the database.
When doing my refresh the Id obviously does not change, but the remaining attributes can.
Now the problem I have is that the Propertychanged is not triggered when item is identical(based on id).

```
Class refreshedItem = await Task.Run(() => backendConnection.GetSchedule(scheduleId, DTOType.Maxi, BackEndSettings.Default.SystemOfMeasurement));
Item = refreshedItem;
```

If I set the Item to a dummy item in between it is triggered every time.

```
Class refreshedItem = await Task.Run(() => backendConnection.GetSchedule(scheduleId, DTOType.Maxi, BackEndSettings.Default.SystemOfMeasurement));
Item = new Class(Guid.Empty) { Title = "test" };
Item = refreshedItem;
```

Comment: You can manually tell it that the property changed. Without seeing more code, I'm not sure exactly what you need to do, perhaps `OnPropertyChanged("Item");`. See [Xamarin Forms - force a control to refresh value from binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124944/xamarin-forms-force-a-control-to-refresh-value-from-binding)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes I know that I can manually trigger a refresh, but I need to understand why it is not automatically triggered because it thinks its the same item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Github Fody Properties Overview](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged#overview), the (default) code that is injected in Item setter is equivalent to

```
if (value != item)
    OnPropertyChanged();
```

It only fires when not equal.

The documentation for Fody Properties says to use Attributes to control its behavior. For what you want, use [DoNotCheckEqualityAttribute](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Attributes#donotcheckequalityattribute).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this and spent hours trying to figure it out...
Thank You!